# What action should the user take when permission to access a page has been removed?

Tags: login, permissions

I'm designing the flow for permission management. In this case, while a user is on a certain screen, their access to that section that screen belongs to is removed. then when the user performs an interaction that refreshes the screen, they would get the following message.

My question is, what options for action should the user be guided to do? They would be logged out. Telling them to try again wouldn't make sense. At the moment, we aren't able to build features to request access either.

[image: you do not have access to this page. We're sorry, your account does not have permission to access this page. Button: continue to log in]

Answer (score 2):

When a user is informed that they no longer have access to the resources they were viewing, they have a choice to make:

1. continue pursuing the goal with a different account
2. abandon their current goal and start something new.

The current design provides them an option for continuing to pursue their goal. The option that's missing is to **help them step back to pursue a new goal**. Consider adding a button that says something like <kbd>Return Home</kbd>, <kbd>Back to Dashboard</kbd>, or similar.

If the larger context of this page still shows the application's navigation, *it might seem redundant, and it is*. However, there is benefit in allowing the user to see both options (e.g. <kbd>Return Home</kbd> and <kbd>Use a different account</kbd>) side by side and act on them explicitly.

Currently, the user sees "Surprise! You've lost access to this page. Now choose from all of the application what to work on next." The user is likely still thinking about the loss of access. Only once they're done with that will they be ready to take a step back and start something new. This button would let them step back when they're ready. This provides an effective mental break for the user to step out of their current workflow before shifting their mindset into what to start next.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell to user, try to contact the support, talk with their manager...
We don't know your solution context, it's hard to give an opinion, but I always say this, talk with your user, test with them, it will be more assertive than hear us.